# Excel Time Conversion Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a worksheet in which there are several dates (dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss) in two columns. In Column A there are start dates and in Column B there are end dates. All I am trying to do is to calculate the difference between those dates. First I do the following formula `=(B2-A2)*1440` and then I just do `=B2-A2`and adjust the cell format to mm:ss and I get two different solutions. Here are my questions. First why is there a difference and secondly why is there a difference?

- Below there are the sample calculations:
- 25.06.2015  09:22:31  25.06.2015  09:24:50
- (B2-A2)*1440 = 2,316666663
- B2-A2 = 02:19

Comment: I format as [mm]:ss and still no change.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the dates.

Comment: 0.316666663 is the same as ¹⁹⁄₆₀.

Comment: So, it is its value in mod(10) then. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you got sorted out. Your regional number formatting threw me for a loop at first but I'm glad the concept got across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.316666663 is the # of minutes, not minutes and seconds.

.316666663 of a minute is 18.999999803491 seconds.

So 2 minutes and 19 seconds.